# Jquery Datatable Row Selection By Id Not Select Row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable and I want to select a row by its Id attribute that equal to the value my javascript variable. The value of variable change dynamicaly. My code is here that i have try:

```
var abc = "0x00033dd";
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(document).ready(function () { 
     var table = $('#datatable').dataTable({   
           "bJQueryUI": true,           
           "stateSave": true,                      
           "bProcessing": true           
       });
      var row = table.row("# + abc").node(); 
      $(row).addClass('selected');
    });
```

But it not work, Please help anyone.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `var row = table.row("#" + abc).node()` ..?  It call all by boiled into `table.row("#" + abc).nodes().to$().addClass('selected')`

Comment: it not work in my program